# Search feature with afnetworking ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using Afnetworking 2.0.
I am developing some complex search features where I need result at every keystroke. i.e when I type something in search bar (above tableview) every char i am firing a query (restful api) which is using afnetworking api..

Scenario:

I type "human" and that word pass to my restful api and api return result and result are displaying in tableview.

I just type "h" and quickly remove "h" it still fire the query which i does not want (something want to cancel the request).. I know there are cancelAll request of afnetworking but my query become fire before cancelAll request execute..

Comment: What you want to do is cancelling the previous request?

Answer (score 0):

You should make custom search bar. you can keep button when press button then only search or call api. other thing you can use `textfield` as search bar having keyboard type websearch and you can call api in delegates like `textfieldshouldreturn` or `textfielddidendediting`. this type of solutions you can made for this kind of requirement. hope this will help :)